# Can Powershell return complete interpolated values using convertfrom-stringdata

Tags: powershell

I have a **.properties** file with the following properties in them:

```
repository.host=hostname.com/nexus
repository.api.url=https://${repository.host}/service/rest/v1
repository.url=https://${repository.host}/repository
```

I am able to return the values using the following powershell function:

```
    static [string] getProperty( [string] $property ){

        $properties = "../resources/vars/$([jenkins]::PROPERTIES_FILE)"
        $properties = get-content $properties | convertfrom-stringdata

        return $properties.$property

    }
```

When attempting to return the property **repository.url** powershell return this string: `https://${repository.host}/repository/`

My question is: Is it possible through features that already exist in powershell for the returned string to be `https://hostname.com/nexus/repository/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, **for security reasons, [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-StringData) does *not* perform string expansion** (interpolation) on its input.

*Assuming you trust the input string*<sup>[1]</sup>, **you can perform the expansion *on demand*, after having read the values from the file**.

Note that use of `ConvertFrom-StringData` is problematic, as you've discovered, because the hashtable it creates invariably has *unordered keys*; that is, the order of the entries does *not* reflect the order in which the properties are defined in the file.
Therefore, processing the hashtable entries can make the on-demand expansion fail, if an out-of-order entry is processed before another entry whose value it needs for the expansion.

The solution is to **roll your own `ConvertFrom-StringData` variant<sup>[2]</sup> that reads the properties into an *ordered* hashtable**.
This additionally allows you to combine the read-from-file and expansion-on-demand tasks:

```bash
# Create a sample properties file.
@'
repository.host=hostname.com/nexus
repository.api.url=https://${repository.host}/service/rest/v1
repository.url=https://${repository.host}/repository
'@ > sample.properties

# Parse the file and build an *ordered* hashtable from it.
$orderedHash = [ordered] @{}
switch -Regex -File sample.properties {
  '^\s*#|^\s*$' { continue } # skip comment and blank lines.
  default {
    # Determine the key and value...
    $key, $value = $_ -split '=', 2
    # ... and create the entry while expanding ${...} references to previous
    #     entries.
    $orderedHash[$key.Trim()] = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString((
      $value.Trim() -replace '\$\{([^}]+)\}', '$$($$orderedHash[''$1''])'
    ))  
  }
}

# Output the result.
$orderedHash
```

- Note the use of method `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString` to perform *on-demand* string expansion (interpolation); since this method isn't easy to discover, [GitHub issue #11693](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11693) proposes that this functionality be surfaced as a proper, easily discoverable *cmdlet* named something like `Expand-String` or `Expand-Template`.

  - Note: In order to be able to use `$ExecutionContext` from the method of a PS *custom class*, you must explicitly reference it in the global scope via `$global:ExecutionContext`.
- For more information about the regex-based `-replace` operator, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

The above yields (note that the input order was maintained):

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
repository.host                hostname.com/nexus
repository.api.url             https://hostname.com/nexus/service/rest/v1
repository.url                 https://hostname.com/nexus/repository
```

---

<sup>[1] Via `$()`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), it is possible to embed *arbitrary commands* in the input strings.</sup>

<sup>[2] The code below does not replicate *all* features of `ConvertFrom-String` data, but it works with the sample input. While it does support skipping comment lines (those whose first non-whitespace character is a `#`) and blank lines, treating `\` as escape characters and supporting escape sequences such as `\n` for a newline is *not* implemented.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The original solution provided by @mklement0 was very useful, and has guided me towards a more complete solution. This solution accomplishes/corrects a couple of things:

- The ability to create the hashtable from a file source.
- The ability to access the `$ExecutionContext` variable from within a class method, using the `$global:` scope.
- The ability to thoroughly parse all keys within the hashtable.

```
    static [string] getProperties ( [string] $file, [string] $property ){

        $properties = get-content $file -raw | convertfrom-stringdata

        while ( $properties.values -match '\$\{([^}]+)\}' ){
            foreach ($key in @($properties.Keys)) {
                $properties[$key] = $global:ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString( ($properties[$key] -replace '\$\{([^}]+)\}', '$$($$properties[''$1''])') )
            }
        }

        return $properties[$property]
    }
```

Note: When the while loop is not present and searching matches of `${*}`, any given returned value may not be completely interpolated or expanded. As an example without the while loop present output from a file may look like this:

```
/nexus
${nexus.protocol}://${nexus.hostname}:${nexus.port}${nexus.context}
${nexus.protocol}://${nexus.hostname}:${nexus.port}${nexus.context}/repository/installers/com/amazon/java/8.0.252/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_252.b09-1.x86_64.rpm
${nexus.protocol}://${nexus.hostname}:${nexus.port}${nexus.context}
${nexus.protocol}://${nexus.hostname}:${nexus.port}${nexus.context}/repository/installers/com/oracle/tuxedo/12.1.3.0.0/p30596495_121300_Linux-x86-64.zip
443
https://hostname.com:443/nexus
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/java/jdk/8u251/jdk-8u251-linux-x64.rpm
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/weblogic/12.2.1.3.0/p30965714_122130_Generic.zip
hostname.com
https
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/weblogic/12.2.1.3.0/p30965714_122130_Generic.zip
```

And if you were to run the same script again (still without the while loop) would look like this:

```
hostname.com
https://hostname.com:443/nexus
/nexus
https://hostname.com:443/nexus
https://hostname.com:443/nexus
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/weblogic/12.2.1.3.0/p30965714_122130_Generic.zip
https://${nexus.hostname}:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/java/jdk/8u251/jdk-8u251-linux-x64.rpm
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/tuxedo/12.1.3.0.0/p30596495_121300_Linux-x86-64.zip
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/amazon/java/8.0.252/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_252.b09-1.x86_64.rpm
443
https
https://${nexus.hostname}:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/weblogic/12.2.1.3.0/p30965714_122130_Generic.zip
```

The reason for the sometimes incompletely interpolated/expanded strings is because hashtables are naturally unordered. With the introduction of the while loop, results will not be returned until all interpolated/expanded strings are resolved.

The official output would look as such:

```
hostname.com
https://hostname.com:443/nexus
/nexus
https://hostname.com:443/nexus
https://hostname.com:443/nexus
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/weblogic/12.2.1.3.0/p30965714_122130_Generic.zip
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/java/jdk/8u251/jdk-8u251-linux-x64.rpm
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/tuxedo/12.1.3.0.0/p30596495_121300_Linux-x86-64.zip
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/amazon/java/8.0.252/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto-devel-1.8.0_252.b09-1.x86_64.rpm
443
https
https://hostname.com:443/nexus/repository/installers/com/oracle/weblogic/12.2.1.3.0/p30965714_122130_Generic.zip
```